# Deleted file taking up space

Tags: storage, bug

A few months ago I deleted a game that was taking up a lot of space on my Mac (all files from the game were removed).
It was a game I downloaded through the Steam application, which I have since moved to another disk, so the game should not be taking up any space on my computer any more.
However, when I manage my storage with System Information, a file from the game (I think the file was the game contents originally) still shows up as taking 13.9 GB of space on my disk.
The "Show in Finder" button doesn't do anything when I click on it and I am unable to delete the file from inside System Information.
I can't locate the file anywhere inside Finder so I'm assuming the file no longer exists on my Mac.

[image]

This is pretty annoying because it is falsely taking up disk space.
Is there a way I can delete this file once and for all?

I am running macOS Mojave 10.14 and I've had this problem since High Sierra.

Comment: did you search for it in Terminal and deleted it there

Comment: Yip. Couldn't find it with terminal either.

Comment: is it a running process or just dormant ? and what are your access rights for it ?

Comment: The screenshot in the post shows all of the information I have on it. I can't find it anywhere else, so I get the feeling it's a bug where System Information is still showing a deleted file. I don't actually know if it is taking up disk space, or whether System Information just thinks it is.

Comment: when you right click o it and do Get Info, what does it shows.

Comment: Right clicking in System Information only gives the option to delete the file. Which I cannot do.

Comment: sorry I meant in Finder.

Comment: or try to find it in About this Mac > System Report > Software . Applications

Comment: It doesn't exist in Finder or in System Report > Software > Applications.